# Converting blocks of code (C/Python/BASH/etc) to syntax-highlit HTML

Tags: html, syntax-highlighting, atom-editor

I am planning to design my own website, which will contain many pages with code-blocks, in several languages (C/C++, Python, BASH, Obj-C, etc)

Some websites have very pretty code blocks, for example:

[image]

(from http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_59_2/mathutils.html)

Is there any publicly available library that allows me to throw in a block of code and returns back pretty HTML?

Ideally only look for something that I can synchronise with my Atom colour scheme.

EDIT: I've found http://syntaxhighlighter.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

I noticed you already found your own answer, but I think it's nice to have **more options**, so here's another one:

Stack Exchange uses this one http://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/README.html

**Live example** (*watch it work*):

```js
exports.create = function(req, res) {
    var article = new Article(req.body);
    article.user = req.user;

    article.save(function(err) {
        if (err) {
            return res.send('users/signup', {
                errors: err.errors,
                article: article
            });
        } else {
            res.jsonp(article);
        }
    });
};
```

***Just how pretty?*** will depend on your implementation of course ;)